# SSIS FTP Task Timeout

Tags: ssis, ftp, timeout, ssis-2012

I set the timeout on SSIS FTP Connection manager to be 300 seconds but randomly during some executions, the package fails within 30 seconds with error on FTP task that reads "An error occurred in the requested FTP operation. Detailed error description: The operation timed out". Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this? Is there a way to enable logging on SSIS native FTP task?

Comment: Check if there's a separate 30 second timeout on the connection manager.

Comment: I actually meant the connection manager, corrected my question to reflect the same.

Comment: In that case check the task (and any parent/container tasks) to see if it has a separate 30 second timeout.

Comment: I tried, I can't find one on the task or even under expressions.

Comment: Is it possible that the remote FTP server is the source of the timeout?  If you have access to them I would check those logs.